# If value match then checkbox checked and update database with checkbox values on submit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying if value is in database show checkbox checked. I checked different value and click on submit button that update database where update value is checkbox checked value.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    include "database_connection.php"; 
    $cutomername = $_GET['username'];
    $productid = $_GET['userid'];
    $cust_id = $_GET['custid'];
    $productid_arr = explode(',' , $productid);
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> <?php echo $cutomername;?></title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form method="post" name="checkboxForm">
    <?php

    $query_flags = "select * from products";
    $row_flags=mysql_query($query_flags); 
    $i=0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($row_flags)){

           $product_id = $row['product_id'];
           $product= $row['product'];
           if($productid_arr[$i] ==$row['product_id']) 
           {
              $check = 'checked="checked"';
           } else{
              $check = '';
           }
           if(in_array($row['product_id'], $chvalues))
           {
              echo  "<input   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\"  id=\"$product_id\" value='" . $row['product_id'] . "' $check />";
           } else{
              echo  "<input  type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\"  id=\"$product_id\" value='" . $row['product_id'] . "' $check/>";
           }
    echo $row['product'];
    echo "<hr />"; 
    $i++;
    }   
    ?>  
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">   

    <?php
    $chvalues = array();
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
       foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $ch => $value)
       {
       $chvalues[] = $value;
       }
    }

    $des_prod_id = implode(',' , $chvalues);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET product_id = '$des_prod_id'  where  ID = '$cust_id'");
   ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to submit form if the checkbox is checked .

Comment: @TusharGupta: i want to checked checkbox value to update database field on submit button.

Comment: Why </input> at last ?

Comment: How could this question/code get 3 upvotes? Ah forgot, people...

Comment: @WigglerJtag what is wrong with question.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want, title is confusing, first sentence is ok, second and third is chaos. Code is total chaos from the formatting to the deprecated functions, unused functions like _fetch_array, escaping double quotes instead of using single quotes. Anyway glad that you found the problem!

Comment: An old question, but worth noting anyway: there's a SQL injection vulnerability in `$cust_id` - look up `mysql_real_escape_string` to defend against this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**finally i solved this problem**

here is my code:

```
<?php
    include "database_connection.php"; 
    $cutomername = $_GET['username'];
    $productid = $_GET['userid'];
    $cust_id = $_GET['custid'];
    $productid_arr = explode(',' , $productid);


 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
     $productid_arr = array();
     foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $ch => $value)
     {
        $productid_arr[] = $value;
     }

    $des_prod_id = implode(',' , $productid_arr);

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET product_id = '$des_prod_id'  where  ID = '$cust_id'");
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> <?php echo $cutomername;?></title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form method="post" name="checkboxForm">
    <?php

    $query_flags = "select * from products";
    $row_flags=mysql_query($query_flags); 
    $i=0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($row_flags)){

           $product_id = $row['product_id'];
           $product= $row['product'];
           if(in_array($product_id, $productid_arr)) 
           {
            $check = 'checked';
            } else{
            $check = '';
            }
        echo  "<input   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\"  id=\"$product_id\" value='" . $row['product_id'] . "' $check />";
        echo $row['product'];
    echo "<hr />"; 
    $i++;
    }   
    ?>  
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">   

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET product_id = $products where  customer_name = $cutomername");
```

to:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET product_id = $value where  customer_name = $cutomername");
```

`$products` should be `$value` because you iterate and assign each element to this variable in your foreach loop.

Comment: @FaceOfJaock : i already check with `$value` but my output is **value not found** that i mention in `else`.